# Русский в консоли Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, консоль, terminal, locale

Я хочу что-бы все ошибки, сообщения, man'ы, выхлопы команд, в общем всё выводились на русском языке в консоли.

Команда

```
export LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
```

Задаёт переменные, и всё бы хорошо, но все равно всё на английском, хоть и

```
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Ни console-cyrillic, ни console-setup ни их реконфигурация не помогают.
Я когда-то решил данную проблему генерацией языковых пакетов, только я не помню как это сделать из консоли.

Comment: Про "кракозябры": какую точно команду выполнили? что ожидали получить? что вместо этого получили? (буквально скопируйте)

Comment: @jfs независимо от команды. Что угодно ввожу в консоль русскими буквами - кракозябры. И вообще хочу полностью руссифицироать консоль.

Comment: Пытались: `LANGUAGE=ru` выставить? (предполагая, что language-pack-ru{,-base} и аналоги уже установлены)

Comment: Кракозябры и "хочу русский для сообщений вместо английского" — это разные вопросы. Обновите ваш вопрос, приведите любой пример команды, ожидаемого вывода и что вы на экране видите.

Comment: Если вас текстовая консоль интересует, то пакет console-setup в Ubuntu 16.04 должен работать. Вот [описание отладки](https://habrahabr.ru/post/281170/).

Comment: Только учтите, что решив эту проблему вы можете получить другую -- при вводе чисел некоторые программы будут требовать десятичную  точку, а другим будет нужна запятая.

Comment: @avp это я переживу. Мне бы решить эту проблему.

Comment: А если в консоли ввести `cyr`?

Comment: @donRumata , command not found

Comment: Это странно, потому что `/usr/bin/cyr` входит в пакет `console-cyrillic`.

Comment: Так а где она задаёт переменные окружения? Если вы выполните `LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 /bin/sh` там тоже нет русского?

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ настрой локали в ubuntu это переключить интерфейс системы (unity) на русский язык из системного апплета (значок шестеренки в даше или верхнем трее). Что бы документация была на русском есть пакет `manpages-ru` и ставится он с помощью команды `sudo apt-get install manpages-ru`