# Отображение кириллицы в консоли

Tags: ubuntu, консоль, terminal

Имеется удалённый сервер с Ubuntu 16.04 . Кириллица на нём отображается некорректно. Некоторые буквы заменяются на вопросительный знак, другие становятся просто невидимыми. Менял способ подключения и устройства, но видимо проблема на самом сервере. В прошлый раз сталкивался с подобным и после долгих поисков в конечном итоге сменил дистрибутив. Что и как нужно сделать, чтобы русские буквы отображались в терминале правильно?

Comment: Связанный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/660787/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8-ubuntu?rq=1)

Comment: Не согласен. Мне не нужен перевод с английского на русский. Нужно только корректное отображение кириллицы. Например, при команды cat Файл_с_русским_текстом.txt . У меня ввод этих букв (название файла) и вывод команды (содержимое) не читабелен.

Comment: где у вас отображается это (putty)? кто имя файла создавал? (загружен по ftp?) какая кодировка файла?

Comment: Вынужден себя поправить. Выяснил, что вывод cat правильный. Но ls нет. Файлы с латиницей в имени читаемые, с кириллицей нет. Не совсем понимаю закономерность этого. Файл загрузил по sftp со своего рабочего компьютера с Ubuntu 18 (использую только стандартный Terminal). Сам файл создан командой echo "Текст" > Файл_c_русским_текстом.txt . Подключаюсь командой ssh user@server.com .

Comment: А комманда `cyr` меняет ситуацию?

Comment: Установил console-cyrillic, но пока без успеха. Команда cyr не запускается: `cyr: This command may be executed only in Linux console`

Comment: Остановился на том, что русуфицировал полностью консоль. При дополнительном гуглении наверняка можно убрать перевод и оставить только шрифты и кодировку. Но раз работает, не трогаю.